# For dynamic StoredProcedure with custom user defined datatype error: Must declare the scalar variable "@myTableType2"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, user-defined-types, sp-executesql

I have to insert bulk data into database and table is also created dynamically.

First have created UserDefined DataTypes

```
-- This is my user  defined type
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Custom_block] AS TABLE(
    [Name] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
    [population] [nvarchar](200) NULL
)
```

Then i have DataTable (C#) which i have to insert into SQL table.

```
--My StoredProcedure :
  CREATE PROCEDURE dumpData(
     @myTableType [Custom_block] readonly,
     @tableName NVARCHAR(200)
    )

AS 
BEGIN
 DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
 Declare @myTableType2 as [Custom_block];
 set @myTableType2=@myTableType;

 SET @sql=N' truncate table '+QUOTENAME(@tableName)+ '
    insert into '+QUOTENAME(@tableName)+' select * from '+@myTableType2

    EXECUTE sp_executesql  @sql
END
```

Error am getting:

> Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure dumpData, Line 12 Must declare
>   the scalar variable "@myTableType2"

Comment: remove `set @myTableType2=@myTableType;` use `insert into select query to copy`..i'm not sure.

Comment: already tried without set `@myTableType2=@myTableType;` not working

Comment: this wont work because you are building a command that ends with "select * from " and than you dont concatinate with a tablename but with a table itself.

Comment: @GuidoG: `insert into tableA select * from tableB ` this query works, but now am making this dynamically as i have to pass table name and datatable as parameter

Comment: yes but is @myTableType2 a varchar with value "tableB" ?

Comment: @GuidoG :` @myTableType2  is set as Custom_block` i.e user defiened type (TABLE)

Comment: @Satindersingh so not a varchar so it wont work just as I said

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't require @myTableType2 you can directly insert values through table valued parameter. Try like this,

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE dumpData (
    @myTableType [Custom_block] readonly
    ,@tableName NVARCHAR(200)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

    SELECT *
    INTO #temp
    FROM @myTableType

    --DECLARE @myTableType2 [Custom_block];
    --SET @myTableType2 = @myTableType;
    SET @sql = N' truncate table ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + '
    insert into ' + QUOTENAME(@tableName) + ' select * from #temp'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql

    DROP TABLE #temp
END
```

Comment: getting this error **Must declare the scalar variable "@myTableType"**

Comment: Same problem, you cannot concatinate a user defined type into the @sql varchar.

Comment: Please check whether you created user defined table type [Custom_block] in your db.

Comment: @GuidoG: There is nothing to do with  '@sql varchar'

Comment: you are doing set @@sql = 'some text' + somevariable. That will only work if somevariable can be casted to a text and if I am not mistaken than @@myTableType2 cannot be casted to a text

Comment: I edited my post. Can you tell me your suggestions on my latest post.

Comment: This might work because now the @sql can be properly concatinated

Answer (score 0):

try to add the tablename as a string..

like

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE dumpData(
 @myTableType varchar(50),
 @tableName NVARCHAR(200)
)
 .....
 SET @sql=N' truncate table '+QUOTENAME(@tableName)+ '
insert into '+QUOTENAME(@tableName)+' select * from '+@myTableType2
```

I guess this would solve your issue

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to explain in my comments, you are spot on

Comment: this wont work, my problem is am using `User Defined Type` .i.e a Table in my case and not `VARCHAR()`

Comment: yes but you cannot concatinate a user defined type into the @sql varchar

Comment: you say that  - execute 'select * from tablename' will not work,since table name is string?

Answer (score 0):

I came with same scenario and solved by creating a table dynamically first and then read the data from temp table

```
DECLARE @insertQuery nvarchar(max)
SET @insertQuery= N'DECLARE @tempTable AS dbo.UserDefinedType
INSERT INTO @tempTable
SELECT ''39140752'',''18e22a74-bee3-462b-aee3-172df46291f3'',''test'' 
SELECT * FROM @tempTable'
EXEC (@insertQuery)
```